# Changing a value in NumPy array to parameter and not to specific value

Tags: numpy, pycharm

Apparantly there is something that is very weird in the assignment to NumPy arrays.

Here's my very simple code:

```
def my_function(r1, r2, N):
    r = np.random.randint(2, size=N)
    ind = np.where(r == 0)
    ind = ind[0]
    print(len(ind))
    print(r[ind])
    np.put(r, ind, r1)
    print(r[ind])
```

I then run in PyCharm console:
my_function(0.9, 1.1, 10)

Output:

```
7
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Question - why wasn't the values changed to 0.9?

If instead of r1 I would explicitly put 0.9 that would have worked. But somehow the reference doesn't work. Tried many options of bypassing. None worked. Help!

Thanks

Comment: `r` is created as an integer array.  When you assign a float it will truncate the value - 0.9 is inserted as 0.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj! I'm suffering from my MATLAB habits...

Comment: It's been a while since I used MATLAB much (though I fire up my Octave interpreter once in a while).  Now that you mention it, it doesn't have a strong `dtype` like numpy.  In Octave a matrix has either a `double` or `char` class.  A numeric matrix shows integers if values are all integer, but it looks like that is just a display feature.  Assign a float to an all integer matrix and the display changes, but the `class` doesn't.